# No suitable constructor found for FacultyListFrame1

Tags: java

I am working on a creating a simple GUI window to manage faculty list,
The error i have is :

```
--------------------Configuration: FacultyListFrame1 - JDK version 1.7.0_02 <Default> - <Default>--------------------
C:\Users\lm_b116\Documents\JCreator Pro\MyProjects\Myfaculty\FacultyListFrame1.java:175: error: no suitable constructor found for Faculty(String,Name,MyDate,boolean)
                    Facultylistframe[noOfFaculty++] = new Faculty(ssnS,new Name(firstName,lastName), new MyDate(month, day, year),selectedStatus);
                                                      ^
    constructor Faculty.Faculty(int,Name,MyDate,double,boolean) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    constructor Faculty.Faculty(int,Name,MyDate) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
Note: C:\Users\lm_b116\Documents\JCreator Pro\MyProjects\Myfaculty\FacultyListFrame1.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 error
```

I would really appreciate any help,

The code for FacultyListFrame1 is :

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import java.awt.*;


public class FacultyListFrame1 extends JFrame {

    private JButton store;
    private JTextArea outputTextArea;
    private JTextField fname, lname, dmonth, dday, dyear, ssalary,nssn,fstatus;
    Faculty Facultylistframe[];
    JComboBox statusSelection;
    int noOfFaculty;
    String[] status={"Fulltime","Parttime"};

    public FacultyListFrame1(int num) {

        super("Faculty List");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        Facultylistframe = new Faculty[num];
        noOfFaculty = 0;

        JLabel jl1 = new JLabel("First Name:");
        add(jl1);
        fname = new JTextField(22);
        add(fname);

        JLabel jl2 = new JLabel("Last Name");
        add(jl2);
        lname = new JTextField(22);
        add(lname);

        JLabel jl7 = new JLabel("SSN:");
        add(jl7);
        nssn = new JTextField(20);
        add(nssn);

        JLabel jl8 = new JLabel("Salary:");
        add(jl8);
        ssalary = new JTextField(20);
        add(ssalary);

        JLabel jl9 = new JLabel("Status:");
        add(jl9);
        statusSelection= new JComboBox(status);
        statusSelection.setMaximumRowCount(2);
        add(statusSelection);

        JLabel jl4 = new JLabel("Birthdate: MM");
        add(jl4);
        dmonth = new JTextField(3);
        add(dmonth);
        JLabel jl5 = new JLabel("DD");
        add(jl5);
        dday = new JTextField(3);
        add(dday);
        JLabel jl6 = new JLabel("Year");
        add(jl6);
        dyear = new JTextField(5);
        add(dyear);



        store = new JButton("Store Data");
        store.addActionListener(new buttonEvent());
        add(store);

        outputTextArea = new JTextArea();
        add(outputTextArea);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int SIZEOFARRAY = 10;
        FacultyListFrame1 plFrame = new FacultyListFrame1(SIZEOFARRAY);

        plFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        plFrame.setSize(380, 500);
        plFrame.setLocation(500, 200);
        plFrame.setVisible(true);

    }

    private class buttonEvent implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            if (e.getSource() != store) return;
            {

                String firstName = fname.getText();
                if (firstName.length() == 0) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No first name", 
                        "Warning", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                    return;
                }

                String lastName = lname.getText();
                if (lastName.length() == 0) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No last name", 
                        "Warning", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                    return;
                }

                String ssnS = nssn.getText();
                int ssn;
                if (ssnS.length() == 0) ssn = -1;
                else
                    try {
                        ssn = Integer.parseInt(ssnS);
                    } catch (NumberFormatException ne) { ssn = -1; }
                if (ssn < 0) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid SSN", 
                        "Warning", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                    return;
                }

                  String salaryS = ssalary.getText();
                int salary;
                if (salaryS.length() == 0) ssn = -1;
                else
                    try {
                        salary = Integer.parseInt(ssnS);
                    } catch (NumberFormatException ne) { ssn = -1; }
                if (salary < 0) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Salary", 
                        "Warning", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                    return;
                }

                String monthS = dmonth.getText();
                int month, day, year;
                try {
                    month = Integer.parseInt(monthS);
                } catch (NumberFormatException ne) { month = 0; }
                String dayS = dday.getText();
                try {
                    day = Integer.parseInt(dayS);
                } catch (NumberFormatException ne) { day = 0; }
                String yearS = dyear.getText();
                try {
                    year = Integer.parseInt(yearS);
                } catch (NumberFormatException ne) { year = -1; }

                int ret = MyDate.checkDate(month, day, year);
                if (ret != 0) {
                    String t="";
                    switch (ret) {
                        case 1: t = "Month"; break;
                        case 2: t = "Day"; break;
                        case 3: t = "Year"; break;
                    }
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, t + " is invalid", 
                        "Warning", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                    return;
                }

                fname.setText("");
                lname.setText("");
                nssn.setText("");
                dmonth.setText("");
                dday.setText("");
                dyear.setText("");
                ssalary.setText("");
                int j=statusSelection.getSelectedIndex();
                boolean selectedStatus=true;
                if(j>0) selectedStatus=false;


                if (noOfFaculty < Facultylistframe.length) 
                    Facultylistframe[noOfFaculty++] = new Faculty(ssnS,new     Name(firstName,lastName), new MyDate(month, day, year),selectedStatus);
                else 
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Faculty List is full", "Warning", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);

            outputTextArea.setText("Last-Name\t First-Name\t SSN\t Salary\t Birth-Date\n");
            for (int i=0; i<Facultylistframe.length; i++) {
                if (Facultylistframe[i]!=null)
                  outputTextArea.append(Facultylistframe[i].toString() + "\n");
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

}

.......................................................................................
Sorry

here is the code for Faculty

```
public class Faculty extends Person{
    private double salary;
    private boolean fullTime;

    public Faculty (int ssn, Name name, MyDate birth)
    {
        super(ssn, name, birth);
    }
    public Faculty (int ssn, Name name, MyDate birth, double salary, boolean f)
    {
        super(ssn, name, birth);
        this.salary = salary;
        fullTime = f;
    }
    public void setSalary (double salary)
    {
        this.salary = salary;
    }
    public double getSalary()
    {
        return salary;
    }
     public void setFullTime (boolean f)
     {
        fullTime = f;
    }
      public boolean getFullTime()
    {
         return fullTime;
     }
    public String toString()
    {
        String faculty = new String ("");
        if (fullTime == false)
            faculty = super.toString() + "\t" + salary + "\t part time ";
        else
            faculty = super.toString() + "\t" + salary + "\t full time ";

        return faculty;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your `Faculty` class.

Comment: The error message says it all: `Faculty` doesn't have a constructor signature for the parameter list you are trying to pass.

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to pass 4 arguments, but according to the error message, the constructors for `Faculty` expect either 3 or 5 arguments.

Either don't pass your `selectedStatus` variable to the constructor, to match `Faculty(int,Name,MyDate)`, or include a `double` value before `selectedStatus` to match `Faculty(int,Name,MyDate,double,boolean)`.

Another alternative: create the 4-argument constructor to match what you are attempting to call: `Faculty(int,Name,MyDate,boolean)`.